# Operator-valued spectral mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

The common holomorphic spectral mapping theorem (SMT) is stated as $f(\sigma(A))=\sigma(f(A))$ where $f$ is holomorphic. I'd like to know if there is a version of SMT for operator-valued functions? For example, I'm now considering $f(A)=Pg(A)P$ where $P$ is a projection and $g$ is a functional calculus.